# Windows display missing after after Ubunutu 14.04 installation. Boot repair didn't solved

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, boot-repair

I have installed windows-7-professional and ubuntu-14.04 on my computer. After installation of both OSes, the display became purple while choosing Windows 7. I tried to fix it using the boot-repair option as given in [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). The problem was solved once only.

When I moved to Windows next time, again display is just a purple screen. Its real head ache to do boot-repair all times. The URL associated with boot-repair is http://paste.ubuntu.com/15462929/.

I would like to add more info on my problem. During startup, my grub shows two Windows loaders, on `sda1` and `sda2` respectively. It is interesting that Windows always has a perfect display without any issue on one of these two loaders.

Suppose, loader on `sda1` works for now, next time loader on `sda1` will not work, but loader on `sda2` will work. It switches always. I tried at-least ten times to confirm. Once the windows loaded, then every thing will work fine. Facing problem in startup screen.

My computer boots in UEFI mode (if it has any importance).

Comment: Your Boot Repair output clearly shows a BIOS/CSM/legacy installation, not an EFI/UEFI installation. (Your firmware may be an EFI, but that's mostly irrelevant if both your OSes are booting in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have UEFI firmware BUT your disk is not GPT style. You are using MBR booting and CSM (BIOS emulation) in firmware by default.

The system report given by your link says that `sda1` is System Reserved and marked as active (boot) partition. This is the place where Windows boot files should be stored.

To fix this issue:

1. Delete `bootmgr` and `/boot` from sda2 (using a Linux Live CD)
2. Use a Windows 7 DVD/USB to repair Windows booting.

   [Repair Windows boot](https://www.boyans.net/RepairWindows/repair-windows-boot.html)
3. Use a Linux live CD to reinstall GRUB.

   [How to Repair, Restore, or Reinstall Grub 2 with a Ubuntu Live CD or USB](http://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-repair-restore-reinstall-grub-2-with-a-ubuntu-live-cd)

Comment: Could you please review my [edits](http://askubuntu.com/posts/751476/revisions) and also review the [editing help](http://askubuntu.com/editing-help) to improve the readability of your answers in the future... **;-)**

Comment: Fabby, thank you for editing my answer, English is not my mother tongue, will try to improve on that ;)